# Request Jenkins Crumb with Github Auth - Missing Overall/Read permissions

Tags: python, jenkins, oauth

I want to give access to a user to the Jenkins job. To simulate his perms, I removed myself from admin group and called `http://<jenkins-url>:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json` using requests library in python. I get error 403 - `Missing Overall/Read permissions`. However, if I type the same url in jenkins where I am logged in using github, I get the crumb properly. Here is my requests call:

```
req = requests.get('http://jenkins-url:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json',
                    auth=('username', 'api-token'))
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get crumb through a python script.

Comment: I'm using Jenkins Job Builder and seem to have the same problem. I'll let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: @GeorgeLund I figured out the problem. I was using Jenkins API key when I actually should have used GitHub token key in api-token

Comment: Thank you - interestingly I seem to be able to use either one of those keys - but only if I'm using an old enough version of python-jenkins. Some change since 0.4.15 seems to prevent passing on of the basic auth credentials at all, at least in some cases. Need to do some more work to figure out what tho!